# Error on getting status from twitter timeline using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am new to tweepy , and I am trying to get my twitter timeline statuses using tweepy. When I am iterating through pagination I am getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Workspace\newtwiiter\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, count=200).pages(15):
  File "D:\Workspace\newtwiiter\tweepy\cursor.py", line 101, in next
    old_parser = self.method.__self__.parser
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__self__'
```

Here is my code,

```
import tweepy
consumer_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
consumer_secret='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_token_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_token_secret='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

page_list=[]
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, count=200).pages(15):
    page_list.append(page)

for page in page_list:
    for status in page:
       print status.text
```

What is wrong I am doing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused due to conflict of some pre-installed packages. When I tried to run this script in `virtualenv` , it is executed without any error.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what pre-installed packages were causing the error/any other workarounds?